# Menu In TextButton Is Not Working

Tags: gxt

I have the following widget class that contains a Sencha TextButton that should display a menu when clicked:

```
public class MyWidget extends Container {

    public interface MyWidgetActionHandler {
        void onClone();
    }

    private final MyData data;

    private final MyWidgetActionHandler handler;

    private TextButton menuButton;

    public MyWidget(MyData data, MyWidgetActionHandler handler) {
        this.data = data;
        this.handler = handler;
        setup();
    }

    private void setup() {
        VerticalLayoutContainer mainContainer = new VerticalLayoutContainer();

        Label dateLabel = new Label(DATE_TIME_FORMAT.format(new Date(data.getApplicability())));
        mainContainer.add(dateLabel);

        menuButton = new TextButton("...");
        Menu menu = new Menu();
        menu.add(new MenuItem("Clone...", new SelectionHandler<MenuItem>() {
            @Override
            public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<MenuItem> event) {
                handler.onClone();
            }
        }));
        menuButton.setMenu(menu);
        mainContainer.add(menuButton);

        setElement((Element) mainContainer.getElement());

        DragSource dragSource = new DragSource(this) {
            @Override
            protected void onDragStart(DndDragStartEvent event) {
                event.setData(data);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The menu is not being displayed when the button is clicked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Add button clickListener then `onClick()` call `menu.show()`.

Menu will not be shown automatically if you don't tell menu to appear.